# Как сгенерировать дату внутри ссылки в коде PHP

Tags: php, api

API

```
<?php 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v1.0/search/?apikey=token&format=json&uid=038AA_tis&from=MOW&to=AMS&lang=ru&thread=false&transport_types=plane&system=iata&show_systems=iata&page=1&date=___________");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json=json_decode($response,true);
   $products=json_decode($response,true);

?>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в ссылке заместо нижнего подчеркивания _______ генерировалась дата форматом «YYYY-MM-DD»
Сайт без CMS на html+PHP Как это реализовать? Спасибо большое заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В начале генерируем саму дату и кладем в переменную:

`$date = date('Y-m-d', time());`

А затем переменную кладем в ссылку:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v1.0/search/?apikey=token&format=json&uid=038AA_tis&from=MOW&to=AMS&lang=ru&thread=false&transport_types=plane&system=iata&show_systems=iata&page=1&date=$date");
```

Если нужно указывать текущее системное время, то `time()` можно не указывать и не добавлять в функцию.

Работу с датами и формат вывода можно посмотреть в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Глупая моя голова!) Принять смогу ответ через 6 минут. Спасибо.

Comment: @Arcadiy я еще уточнил на всякий случай, что если нужно указывать текущее системное время, то `time()` можно не указывать и не добавлять в функцию. А так в `time()` можно задать что угодно если понадобиться

Comment: Да, еще раз спасибо